# Non Linear regression for Finding parameters in Python

Tags: python, non-linear-regression

I have a function Y=a+b*(x)^c and a List of experimental values of x and y. How can I do curve fitting for it in python and find out the value of parameters a,b and c?

```
x         y
5.107     3.57
15.593    4.09
178.942   9.19
351.23    14.3
523.172   19.41
1039.449  32.17
```

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use `lmfit` (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) and define a model function, say as

```
import numpy as np
from lmfit import Model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array((5.107, 15.593, 178.942, 351.23, 523.172, 1039.449))
y = np.array((3.57, 4.09, 9.19, 14.3, 19.41, 32.17))

def expfunc(x, scale, decay, offset):
     "model exponential decay with offset"
    return offset + scale*x**decay

# create model from the above model function
model = Model(expfunc)

# create parameters with initial values, 
# using names from model function
params = model.make_params(offset=0, scale=1, decay=1)

# fit data 'y' to model with params
result = model.fit(y, params, x=x)

# print and plot result 
print(result.fit_report())
result.plot_fit()
plt.show()
```

The fit report for this fit will give fitting statistics and best-fit values, uncertainties, and correlations for the parameters:

```
[[Model]]
    Model(expfunc)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 27
    # data points      = 6
    # variables        = 3
    chi-square         = 0.181
    reduced chi-square = 0.060
    Akaike info crit   = -15.015
    Bayesian info crit = -15.640
[[Variables]]
    offset:   3.29036599 +/- 0.200622 (6.10%) (init= 0)
    scale:    0.06290220 +/- 0.008912 (14.17%) (init= 1)
    decay:    0.88280026 +/- 0.020216 (2.29%) (init= 1)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are <  0.100)
    C(scale, decay)              = -0.997
    C(offset, scale)             = -0.722
    C(offset, decay)             =  0.686
```

and produce a plot like this:

[image]

FWIW, this model function is simple enough that you could use an lmfit `ExpressionModel` to build the model from the string of the expression, as with:

```
from lmfit.models import ExpressionModel
model = ExpressionModel('offset + scale*x**decay')
```

with all else the same as above.